# R Read and Transform Lines in a File

Tags: regex, r, gsub, readfile

I have a horribly formatted log file (I cannot changed how it is created) that I wish to do some analysis on.

I have a regex that matches specific lines in the log file. These lines contain bits of data (strings and numbers, that will be caught by matching groups in the RegEx) that I want to extract and put into a matrix before the analysis.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Using the `gsub` function maybe? (I'm very new to R)

**Edit**, to address the comments.

I can't post the log file contents but I can give an example of what I want:

My log file looks like so:

```
....
[Node_1] sometext [Ref:1111111, Strategy:4] Initialise Class1
[Node_1] sometext [Ref:1111111, Strategy:4] Initialise Class1 - 3432ms
some non relevant text
more non relevant text
[Node_4] sometext [Ref:1133311, Strategy:5] Run Class76
[Node_4] sometext [Ref:1133311, Strategy:6] Run Class76 - 5432ms
....
```

I only want to read in the lines which have timings at the end and I want the corresponding lines in the matrix to include bits of data in the lines.

So if My regex looks like this:

```
^\[([^]]*)\][^[]*\[([^]]*)\] (Initialise|Run) (Class[0-9]+) - ([0-9]+)ms$
```

I want the line in the matrix to be

```
\1,\2,\4,\5
```

I.E for the 2nd line in the log file, the line in the matrix would read:

```
Node_1, "Ref:1111111, Strategy:4", Class1, 3432
```

Comment: Please show us a (small) example of your log file, your regex pattern and your desired output and then we can chime in (edit your original post, don't paste it under comments).

Comment: @Arun, thanks for looking, I've added the relevant info you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strapplyc](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gsubfn/docs/strapply) in the [gsubfn](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) package can pull out captures:

```
pat <- 
"^\\s*\\[([^]]*)\\][^[]*\\[([^]]*)\\] (Initialise|Run) (Class[0-9]+) - ([0-9]+)ms$"

Lines <- "....
[Node_1] sometext [Ref:1111111, Strategy:4] Initialise Class1
[Node_1] sometext [Ref:1111111, Strategy:4] Initialise Class1 - 3432ms
some non relevant text
more non relevant text
[Node_4] sometext [Ref:1133311, Strategy:5] Run Class76
[Node_4] sometext [Ref:1133311, Strategy:6] Run Class76 - 5432ms
...."

# read in file
Lines2 <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
closeAllConnections()

# extract lines ending in ms
Lines3 <- grep("ms$", Lines2, value = TRUE)

# pull out captures
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(Lines3, pat, simplify = "rbind")[, -3]
```

The result of the last line is:

```
     [,1]     [,2]                      [,3]      [,4]  
[1,] "Node_1" "Ref:1111111, Strategy:4" "Class1"  "3432"
[2,] "Node_4" "Ref:1133311, Strategy:6" "Class76" "5432"
```